# What are the quiz questions?

Tags: yooka-laylee

These quizzes are very annoying, with some questions nearly impossible for a regular player to get on the first or even second try. Quackers even references "Yookapedia" as if we're expected to look them up online, but there isn't a full list available (or, as of now, a "Yookapedia").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quackers asks custom questions, which depend on your personal stats, so check them: number of quills, pagies, power-ups collected, length of playtime

- Quills (Legal property of Hivory Towers)... how many do you have in total?
- Those bogus Butterfly Boosters... how many have you stolen so far?

  - Same format for Pagies "stolen" (overall and specifically from Hivory Towers hub)
- How long has it taken you to get this far?

  - Check your playtime

## Questions shared between Quackers quizzes

- This quiz... how many hexagons are on the board?

  - 10
- How many wheels do I have?

  - 3

## Quiz #1

- The character... who is it?

  - Clara (pith helmet)
- The picture... where was it taken?

  - Rextro's Arcade (purple trim)
- Colour of Capital B statue

  - Gold

## Quiz #2

- The character... who is it?

  - Planker (signpost)
- The picture... where was it taken?

  - Rextro's Arcade (rainbow on walls)
  - Under the palace (frozen lock)
  - Igloo Village (door)
- Rextro's Stinky Arcade... how many playable units does it have?

  - 8
- Your health meter... how many butterflies did it start with?

  - 6
- Clara... what does she need you to save on Glitterglaze Glacier?

  - Her pot
- Rextro's Ridiculous Arcade... what game does Rextro's Arcade not have?

  - ???
- The Moodymaze Marsh trolley with the stupid hat... what business does it own?

  - Farmers market
- Moodymaze marsh trolleys... which one wears a stupid hat?

  - Walley
- The Ridiculous fish bowl wearing Dr. Puzz... what was her second transformation?

  - Snowplough

## Quiz #3

- The character... who is it?

  - Planker (signpost)
- The picture... where was it taken?

  - Capital Cashino (security camera)
  - Tribalstack Tropics? (grassy area)
  - Not Galaxy? (purple sky)
- Capital Cashino... statues around the fountain

  - Corplets
- Capital Cashino... what can you exchange for tokens?

  - Pagies
- World with the gambling, what is its name

  - Capital Cashino
- This adventure's corporations... which is clearly the best?

  - Hivory Towers
- The crooked salesman, Trowzer, what was the first move he taught you?

  - Tail Twirl

## Pagie quiz in Glitterglaze Glacier's Icymetric Palace

- Color of pipes in room: red
- Number of torches in room: 7
- Number of torches AND crates: 10
- See [the list at USgamer](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/18-04-2017-yooka-laylee-glitterglaze-glacier-pagie-locations-butterfly-heart-power-extender-play-coin-mollycool) for more